# Do screen readers understand HTML escape characters (like &quot; for double quotes)?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I'm updating a aria-label value method that's currently escaping the value to be safely used in a HTML element attribute.

So it would convert `<span> abc"` to `&lt;span&gt; abc&#34;`, for example.

The issue is that the JAWS reads it as it is, it doesn't translate the encoding.

Is this a characteristic of all (or most) of the screen readers? Or that's just a bug?

My initial solution for this would be to convert the symbols that requires (or is usually) to be escaped (<,>, ", ', and &) to its name (e.g. < would be converted to "less than"). Is this a valid solution?

Answer (score 1):

So your `aria-label` is going to include HTML entities? I'm not sure I follow that scenario. An aria-label is just announced as is and special characters don't have to be escaped. So if you want an aria-label to say "<span>", you can just have `aria-label="<span>"`.  The aria-label isn't rendered so nothing has to be escaped.

Now, most screen readers have a "verbosity" setting so some punctuation and special characters are not announced by default, but the user has total control over that.  So in the `aria-label="<span>"` example, a screen reader might only say "*span*". But if the user changes their verbosity to read all special characters, then it might say "*less than, span, greater than*".

Comment: "The aria-label isn't rendered so nothing has to be escaped." I'm not the OP but I don't think this is necessarily right. It sounds like they're using some sort of generic function to insert an `aria-label` attribute directly into the HTML, and in that case it must of necessity escape certain characters, lest someone input an "aria-label" of `foo" <script>/* some evil JS */</script> foo="`. (Of course this depends on who can provide this input but most such utiliies quite rightly err on the side of caution.) I agree that if the label is being set by JS there's no issue.

Comment: just realised my attempted injection attack was malformed as you can't have a script inside the HTML element tag, but that doesn't disprove my point - a more intelligent attacker than me could easily close off the tag, complete with dummy content, then insert their script. The point is that when you're building HTML by string concatenation you're always open to exploits like this.

Comment: @RobinZigmond What part isn’t right about the aria-label not being rendered? It’s never displayed other than if you have the captions panel open for voiceover or a similar feature in nvda or jaws.

Comment: I wasn't questioning that part, but the conclusion you draw from it that "nothing has to be escaped". In any case, from reading the OP again, whether it actually needs to be escaped here isn't really important, the fact is that whatever function/utility the OP is using is doing that.

Comment: It’s still accurate that nothing has to be escaped in the aria-label. It’s just plain text that will be announced by the screen reader so you don’t need to replace ’<‘ with ‘&LT;’

Answer (score 0):

Your intention aren't very clear, but:

- The content of aria-label, as with all other HTML attributes, must in principle only be plain text. HTML isn't allowed. So it's perfectly normal if your content is taken directly as is by the screen reader.
- Except in specific contexts such as programming, math, etc. where they are meaningful, it's generally a bad idea to include special symbols such as "<" in a label. A label must just be plain text, there shouldn't be any sort of useless decoration. That's just noise for the screen reader user.
- It's generally a very bad idea to replace a symbol which is perfectly readable/accessible as is by a literal description of it.

About point 1: if you need to add HTML in your label, consider changing your aria-label to aria-labelledby and reference an actual HTML element, possibly positionned off-screen / visually hidden, where you have the whole freedom of using HTML.
Consider also that solution if you need to add line breaks (\n) or tabulations (\t), as they may not be supported in aria-label everywhere either.

Note that putting HTML in the title attribute seem to be quite popular with some frameworks, but, in fact, completely wrong, and will result in having the HTML code read by the screen reader.

About point 3:
It's generally a very bad idea to replace a symbol which is perfectly readable/accessible as is by a literal textual description of it.
IN many languages, these symbols can have different names, and the user will be confused if he/she doesn't  get the same name as used to. For exemple, "<" can be viewd as "less than" but also as "open angle paren" or "left angle paren".
Additionally, it will double confuse braille users, because they are going to literally read "less than" written in full on their braille display instead of the single braille "<" character they are used to. Be it in a place where "<" is meaningful or not, that's at best a waste of time and energy to understand what it actually means.

Comment: While much of what you say is inaccurate, I think you've misunderstood the OP's situation. I don't think they *want* to inject HTML into the aria-label, just to use special characters that the utility they're using will replace with HTML entities (for perfectly legitimate security reasons), thereby losing their meaning to screenreaders. But then I agree with you that characters like "<" shouldn't usually be part of a label so without seeing a concrete example it's hard to see the real problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer QuentinC. Well I actually forgot about the translation to other languages. Well I don't have a reason why the customer would want to insert a html tag in the value, but it's possible, the application i work on doesn't check that.

Comment: If slugolicious int the comment bellow is right regarding the content not being rendered inside aria-label, then my worry would just be the quotes, that if present in the string closes the attribute

Comment: *late correction but in my first sentence of my previous comment I meant to say `While much of what you say is *accurate*`. Apologies for the unintended slight!